# From which math font is this character taken?

Tags: fonts

Does anyone have an idea from which math font this character is taken (for the `\mathbb{E}` command)?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it's from `dsfont`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}
\(\mathds{E}\)
\end{document}
```

If you want to use this font with `\mathbb`, you can use [`mathalpha`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha) with option `bb=dsfontserif`. The following example gives the same output as above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[bb=dsfontserif]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
\(\mathbb{E}\)
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick answer!